# How to restrict a Jenkins job on EC2 spot fleet?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

I have installed the EC2 spot fleet plugin in Jenkins to use EC2 machines as slaves.
I want only a particular job to be executed on this EC2 fleet.

However, whilst restricting a label to this job where it should runn; every label is now being served by this Amazon EC2 fleet.

Whereas, a particular job should run on this EC2 fleet, since the instances on this fleet are configured to run only this job and not the other jobs.

Before creating spot fleet:
[image]

Creating the spot fleet:
[image]

After Adding the spot fleet:
[image]

So, now every label is using this spot fleet to serve the requests assigned to it. However, this spot fleet can run only a particular job.

How can this be solved so that only a particular job runs on this spot fleet?

Comment: Just need to check how you have your nodes configured. In Manage Nodes, does your master have something like this? http://i.imgur.com/887fUjs.png

Comment: @Return_Of_The_Archons Hi.
I downloaded the source code for the plugin and built a new version of it where the label can be mentioned. Only the specific job now runs on this fleet; but now the plugin cant connect to the EC2 windows instances which in itself is a known issue (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Windows+slaves+fail+to+start+via+DCOM) and a HUGE pain for me. Can you please guide with the same. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any nodes configured?

Comment: @Return_Of_The_Archons Hi. I tried configuring the nodes as mentioned on the link https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Windows+slaves+fail+to+start+via+DCOM. All vain. Very difficult.

Comment: Can you post the node config? Take a screenshot and upload to imgur.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from version [1.5.0](https://github.com/jenkinsci/ec2-fleet-plugin/releases/tag/ec2-fleet-1.5.0) EC2 Fleet Jenkins Plugin has property:

`Only build jobs with label expressions matching this node`

When checked only properly labled jobs will be executed on plugin nodes.